# how to test existence of context variable using gulp-file-include

Tags: if-statement, testing, gulp

I am using `gulp-file-include` to build my html pages using some partials & templates. By using context variables, I can customize each `meta` headers. However, don't know how I could include a line **only if** a context variable exists, as the "@@else" statement doesn't seem to exist.

My parent HTML looks like:

```
@@include ('_header.html', {
    "title":"my page",
    "description": "description",
    "canonical":"http://www.sourcefromquote.com" })

<body>
    A wonderful Page 
    @@include ('_footer.html")
</body></html>
```

I was thinking to use a `_header.html` close to something like that :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>@@title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="@@description">
    @@if (canonical) {  <link rel="canonical" href="@@canonical" /> }
</head>
```

If the "canonical" variable is not set in the the parent HTML, it throws an error (`canonical is not defined`).

I guess I could include the full  tag in a variable and forget about the `@@if`, but that would not be as clean as expected !

Any ideas ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

In the head, you enter:

```
@@if (context.canonical) {<link rel="canonical" href="@@canonical" />}
```

In the file that includes the header you enter:

```
@@include('_head.html', {
  "canonical" : "https://www.website.com/canonical-link.html"
})
```